# Matrix reconstruction from sums

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I want to reconstruct a matrix with all positive integer elements, given the sum of every row and column.

```
a0 a1 a2 .. aN | Σa
b0 b1 b2 .. bN | Σb
.. .  .  .  .. | ..
..  .  .  . .. | ..
z0 z1 z2 .. zN | Σz
---------------+----
Σ0 Σ1 Σ2 .. ΣN |
```

Is there an algorithm which will find *all* possible matrix element combinations, given the row and column sums.

Any reference is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you have is a [system of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations), one for each row and one for each column; m*n variables and m+n equations.

How to calculate (and represent) the set of solutions solve such a system depends on what your environment is.

**EDIT:** I see. For large instances of this problem, see [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

But if youre matrix and row / column sum are small, it will be possible to find all solutions by [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Very high-level pseudocode:

```
function SOLVE(partially filled M) {

    if (M has no empty entries) {

        M is a solution

    } else {

        ij <- one empty position of M
        // in practice, try picking one that reduces the number of
        // iterations of the following loop

        for (each possible value v of M[ij], subject to the constraints) {
            M' <- a copy of M
            M'[ij] = v
            SOLVE(M')
    }
}


M0 <- an empty Matrix of correct size

SOLVE(M0)
```

Comment: How does the resulting system of linear equations ensure that the matrix entries are positive (where probably "non-negative" is actually meant)?

Comment: basically the environment would be like inputting the row and column sums and getting the output of all possible set of matrices which satisfy those sums.